# Coin Game Problem number of ways to win when input is 7

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am working on the classic coin game problem:
Alice and Bob are playing a game using a bunch of coins. The players pick several coins out of the bunch in turn. Each time a player is allowed to pick 1, 2 or 4 coins, and the player that gets the last coin is the winner. Alice picks the first.
 
 I am actually don't understand how the out comes.

```
    coinGame(1)= ('Alice', 1)
    coinGame(2) = ('Alice', 1)
    coinGame(3) = ('Bob', 2)
    coinGame(4) = ('Alice', 3)
    coinGame(5) = ('Alice', 2)
    coinGame(6) = ('Bob', 6)
    coinGame(7) = ('Alice', 8).
```

I understand the output of 1,2,3...6, but I don't understand the 7 and afterward.
For input 6, since Alice will always reach coin 2, 4 and 5. Therefore, Bob just needs to pick any of 1, 2 or 4 to win the game. The total way is  1 + 3 + 2 = 6
For input 7, Bob can reach 3 and 6, then Alice just pick 4 or 1 coins to win the game with 2 + 6 = 8 ways to win. What I don't understand is that, for input 7, Alice can also reach 5, then Bob just picks 2 to win. Why we ignored this case and considers Alice win?

I hope I can get some clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: what does the input to `coinGame` represent and what does the output represent? `(winner, ?)`

Comment: @ChrisGong Is the algorithm to calculate the result, and the number is the number of ways to win.

Comment: It is assumed both players play perfectly. This is like the game of nim, you have to go from a winning position to a losing position to still win. So as you said, from 7 Alice can go to 6 or 3, so you can just add the number of ways for 6 and 3, which is 2 + 6 = 8. Alice wouldn't make a losing move and go to 5, unless Alice has no winning move, then you add the number of ways for taking 1, 2 and 4 coins, that's why for 6 there are 2 + 3 + 1 = 6 ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One key point
If Bob wins the game then there are some strategies where person starting the game is going to loose. 
If Alice wins the game then person starting the game is winning.

So from each N check if there is any winning position of Bob in N-1, N-2, and N-4.
if yes then Alice is going to win with the sum of the positions where Bob is winning.

If Alice is winning from N-1, N-2 and N-4 then Alice is definitely going to loose this game from N.
Because person starting game from positions N-1, N-2 and N-4 is winning the game.
When Alice pass the turn to Bob then Bob will get only one in N-1, N-2 and N-4.
And person starting game from these positions is going to win the game.

```
N>=5
sum=0
if Bob wins in N-1
    sum+=coinGame(N-1).count
if Bob wins in N-2
    sum+=coinGame(N-2).count
if Bob Wins in N-4 
    sum+=coinGame(N-4).count

if sum==0
   Bob wins with coinGame(N-1).count + coinGame(N-2).count + coinGame(N-4).count
else
   Alice wins with sum
```

**Finding coinGame(7)** 
Given 
coinGame(3) = ('Bob', 2)       7-4
coinGame(5) = ('Alice', 2)     7-2
coinGame(6) = ('Bob', 6)       7-1

Bob is winning the game from 6 with count 6 and from 3 with count 2
So Alice will win the game from 7 by count 8